# 5 Years Since Proposal!

Tags: discussion

[I blogged about it](http://www.laceysnr.com/time-flies-and-communities-grow/) but I suspect a lot of our users won't see that...

Just wanted to call out that it's been 5 years since I proposed this site on Area 51. I think most would agree it's been a great success and that's entirely down to our amazing user base. Thank you to all of you, you've saved me many, many headaches over the years. Not least that Foxy guy.

Comment: 5 years and counting. Thanks everyone for your help and support.

Comment: Here's..... to the next 5?!!

Comment: Hrmm... I definitely saw the blog post, but I can't remember what led me to it. Twitter feed most likely. Pretty good idea, by the way!

Comment: Here here.......

Comment: I'd have been hosed w/o this site when I started coding Apex and VF in earnest. So much better than the SF Developer Forum

Comment: I appreciate that foxy guy shares lots of knowledge (shout out to @sfdcfox).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Thank you so much for making that proposal. I've learned so much on this site, both by reading people's answers and providing them myself. Many of the wonderful people here inspire me. I won't name anybody because then I'll surely omit someone who's made a difference. But I find joy in this site nearly every day, and I'm looking forward to its continued success!

Comment: Very well said! #VeryTrue

Comment: Very true. I came from a PHP background with no MVC experience at all. Since then I've come a long way in large part thanks to SFSE and her many contributors. Often, I found I learn as much answering questions as I do asking them!